# Magento 2 rest api webapi.xml rules for GET parameters

Tags: magento2, rest-api

`http://localhost:8888/rest/all/V1/api/orders/?from=31.05.2020&to=31.06.2020`

My webapi xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/api/orders/" method="GET">
        <service class="Lovat\Api\Api\OrdersRepositoryInterface"
                 method="get"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Is it possible to add `from` and `to` parameters to this route?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible.

> Note - to make them required you can keep the "force" attribute true, else false.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/api/orders/" method="GET">
        <service class="Lovat\Api\Api\OrdersRepositoryInterface"
                 method="get"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
        <data>
            <parameter name="from" force="true">%from%</parameter>
            <parameter name="to" force="false">%to%</parameter>
        </data>
    </route>
</routes>
```

And your Interface should be like this

```
/**
 * @param string $from
 * @param string|null $to
 * @return string
 */
public function get($from, $to = null);
```

> Notice that I've kept $to as null because we have not made it required.

Comment: i have this errror "message": "Class from does not exist",
    "code": -1,

Comment: can you share your Lovat\Api\Api\OrdersRepositoryInterface as well

Comment: I've also updated my answer for changes in Interface file

Comment: @AfreenSheikh, nicely explained.

Comment: @HiteshBalpande Thanks :)

Comment: my OrdersRepositoryInterface
interface OrdersRepositoryInterface
{
    public function get($from, $to): string;
}

Comment: change it to as I've mentioned in the answer.

Comment: ok, thanks!
my url http://localhost/rest/all/V1/api/orders/?from=eqwwqe&to=321321
answer all time string(6) "%from%"
string(4) "%to%"

Comment: you mean you want to add validation of date?

Comment: I want these parameters to be required and accept data without writing extra code
but now my result it's %from% and %to%, no matter what parameters I specify on $_GET

Comment: I've mentioned in the answer how to make the param required. make the "force" attribute as "true".